# Spread Haskell Singleton definition among modules

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I’m using the `singletons` and `singletons-th` libraries, and I want (if possible) to split a singleton definition between files. I tried creating a data family, but I’m getting a `Declaration cannot be promoted` error.

```hs
data family Field
data family SField :: Field -> Type

singletons
  [d|

  data instance Field = Field1 | Field2
  |]

>>> Other file:
singletons
  [d|
  data instance Field = Field3
  |]
```

How could I split the singleton definition between two or more files?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems, one of them nothing to do with splitting between files nor TH.

- "Data family instance constructors cannot be promoted at the moment. GHC’s type theory just isn’t up to the task of promoting data families, which requires full dependent types." [says the User Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.5/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overview) I think that explains the `cannot be promoted` error. So you can't define `SField` like that.
- A `data family` should have a type parameter (same as a class). Something like `data family Field a; ... data instance Field Int = ...; data instance Field Char = ...;`. Without a parameter, you can define only one instance, and all its constructors would have to be in that instance.

Why is it you're trying to define a `data family`, and why via TH/what's the use case here?

Comment: The use case is defining a huge singleton, with about 100 singletons split between two modules. I've used a Data family because that's what the library seemed to use, but I'm happy with whatever approach that lets me split the definition between the two modules.

Comment: Btw, the data family has a Kind of `Field -> Type`, (or `Field-> * `) so it has a parameter, but is defined in other syntax

Comment: Then what does `Field1, Field2, Field3` mean? And why do they have to be defined in separate modules? Whatever your "in other syntax" means, your code doesn't show syntax for a type parameter to the `data family`, so you _don't_ have a parameter.

Comment: It's true, families can't be promoted (yet) but it's an open issue in GitHub